# how to load dynamic image from path in microsoft report viewer using c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reporting-services, reportviewer

Dears
Im using Microsoft reportviewer in my asp.net core project to generate a pdf report .

I want to set an external path from my files into the header section as a logo ,

I'm tying to do that not by report designer , i need to do that at runtime by c# code.

im using this code to generate report

```
public static byte[] GenerateReport(string reportName, string reportHeader, List<ReportDataSource> DataSets, LanguageEnum language, bool setLanguage = true, string returnExtension = "Pdf", string reportParams = "")
{
    ReportViewer EMSReportViewer = new ReportViewer();
    EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
    SetReport(EMSReportViewer, reportName, language, setLanguage, reportParams);

    EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = getLabel(reportHeader, language);
    EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    foreach (ReportDataSource dataset in DataSets)
        EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset);

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamids;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string filenameExtension;

    byte[] bytes = EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.Render(returnExtension, null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
    return bytes;
}
```

can you help me  please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a external images then you need to pass it as a `ReportParameter`.

Example:

```
     public static byte[] GenerateReport(string reportName, string reportHeader, 
        List<ReportDataSource> DataSets, LanguageEnum language, bool setLanguage = 
        true, string returnExtension = "Pdf", string reportParams = "")
     {
        ReportViewer EMSReportViewer = new ReportViewer();
        EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        
        //ReportParameter
        var parameter = new ReportParameter("ImagePath","-Your Image Path--");
        EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);
    
        SetReport(EMSReportViewer, reportName, language, setLanguage, reportParams);
    
        EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = getLabel(reportHeader, language);
        EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        foreach (ReportDataSource dataset in DataSets)
            EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset);
    
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;
    
        byte[] bytes = EMSReportViewer.LocalReport.Render(returnExtension, null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: thank you its work ,, 

but my issue is i already have embedded image in my report and i need to replace it with another image